# VB.NET - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 34

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

```
Dim path As String = xlPath
        Dim conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;MaxScanRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text';")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dtset As DataSet

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(conString)
        cmd.Connection = MyConnection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = query

        Dim MyCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        dtset = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dtset)

        Dim dtb As DataTable = dtset.Tables(0)
```

I Have a connection string in VB.NET which works fine for me as well as other bunch of users. But there is one user who is getting this error **"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 34"**

When i checked the character at Index 34 its the end of Provider "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0".
Is there any problem with the code or is there something missing in the Users system?

Comment: This is not the point where the error occurs. Please post the code that tries to use this connection string.

Comment: On a tangential note, there's no point in calling `String.Format` if you're going to use concatenation *instead of* format placeholders, e.g. `{0}`. In fact, you would end up with an exception if the value of `path` included a placeholder.

Comment: @Steve I have Updated the full code now

Comment: @madreflection Good Point. I will have to check the address where the user has stored the excel file.

Comment: Don't "check the address". You've missed the point. Use ***either*** concatenation ***or*** `String.Format`, not both. It's perfectly valid to have something like "{0}" in a file's path, so you can't remove the placeholder or reject the path.

Comment: Same version of excel on all users machines?

Comment: Furthermore, the path may be OK *now* but that doesn't mean it couldn't be changed in the future (unless you're hard-coding it... *\*shiver\**).

Comment: Also the connection, command and adapter need `Using` blocks to dispose them

Comment: That one user probably has some different environmental settings that perhaps is throwing off the expected value of Path.  Assuming that the Path variable is correct in what ever config you have for that user.  Although using either string concatenation OR String.Format are both valid ways to build the connection string, perhaps you might find using a Connection String Builder object a little more robust